# Tweenjs Blurring inside Container

Tags: javascript, easeljs, tween.js

I've been stuck on this for about a week now and can't figure out why the shape instance inside my container is getting blurred when it is animated at 60 fps. My container holds one shape instance. The shape instance is associated with one graphics instance. There seems to be a white blur that trails the direction of the animation. Is there a way to stop this blurring or is it a limitation of tweenJS? Here's the jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/1chh2de6/

Here are some additional details, I am working on a billiards game which involves a lot of moving circles. I've created a class for each pool ball, which will hold more shape instances in the future. However, at 60 fps the shape instances are blurred during animations. Here's the 'poolBall' class.

```
function poolBall(number, posX, posY) {
    this.number = number;
    this.shapesArray = []; 
    this.shapesArray.push(new createjs.Shape()); 
    this.containerInstance = new createjs.Container();
    this.containerInstance.addChild(this.shapesArray[0]);
    this.containerInstance.x = posX;
    this.containerInstance.y = posY;
    this.drawGraphic = function(){
        this.shapesArray[0].graphics.beginFill('white')
            .setStrokeStyle(1)
            .beginStroke("#000000")
            .drawCircle(14, 14, 14)
            .endFill()
            .endStroke();
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a symptom of how the canvas displays the contents as they change, and not related to EaselJS or TweenJS. Here is a fiddle using raw canvas APIs.

http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/97vLu9q9/1/

**Circle Code**

```
context.beginPath();
context.arc(0,0,20,0,2* Math.PI,false);
context.fillStyle = "white";
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.stroke();
```

Note that I used RequestAnimationFrame to update the stage. I tested RAF with EaselJS as well, with no change in how it animated.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something here, this is just persistence of vision, which is just how normal human vision works, especially with high contrast graphics on computer screens.

Try going outside on a dark night and waving a bright light back and forth, you will similarly see a subtle "trail" behind it.

An even better way to prove this, is to capture a screen shot while the animation is happening. Looking at the static frame, you will see that it does not have the blur.

Comment: Playing with this more, it seems like it might also be related to display technology in some way. Changing the background color will change the intensity of the effect, with green being the worst. Similarly, its more pronounced on some screens. On my laptop screen its very visible, on my secondary monitor, its hardly visible at all. Interesting.

Comment: This site should demo everything you ever wanted to know about LCDs and motion blur: http://www.testufo.com/#test=ghosting&background=004000&separation=1000&pps=1080&pursuit=0